# put multiple files to one zip folder before downloading on client side reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, loops, download

I have two functions here that takes an array of file keys, and passes it to a download function that will download each file individually from aws s3.

I would like to have all the files together in one zip folder and just download that one zip folder, so that all the files are together.

**Questions:**

**1st** How would I first set the directory to save the files to?

**2nd** How would I put all the files that are being downloaded in to one zip folder, then download the zip folder?

any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

**current code**

```
async function handleDownloadClick(event) {
         event.preventDefault();

      const imagesAsArray = [...imagesUploaded];

        for (let i = 0; i < imagesAsArray.length; i++) {                      

            await DownloadFile(imagesAsArray[i]);

        }
    }


    async function DownloadFile(fileToDownload) {

    const filename = `${fileToDownload.key}`;

   const result = await Storage.get(fileToDownload.key, {download: true})

        console.log(result)
        let mimeType = result.ContentType

        let fileName = fileToDownload.key.split(`${job.jobId},/`)

        console.log(fileToDownload.key)

        try {
          let blob = new Blob([result.Body], {type: mimeType})

          //downloading the file depends on the browser
          //IE handles it differently than chrome/webkit
          if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName)
          } else {
            let objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            let link = document.createElement('a')
            link.href = objectUrl
            link.setAttribute('download', fileName)
            document.body.appendChild(link)
            link.click()
            document.body.removeChild(link)
          }
        } catch (exc) {
          console.log("Save Blob method failed with the following exception.");
          console.log(exc);
        }

   }
```

**Updated Code doing what I needed it to do**

figured I would share my solution, as i've seen alot of questions about this, but not many helpful answers.

using JSZip: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

using `saveAs` from fileSaver.js: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

**First:** it loops through downloading each file individually from s3, creates a blob, and puts each blob/file into a "folder".

**Second:** after each file has been downloaded from s3, it will then use the saveAs method to download/save the zipped folder.

```
function NewEditInfo(props) {
const [job, setJob] = useState([]);
const [imagesUploaded, setImagesUploaded] = useState(null); 

//initialize jsZip
var JSZip = require("jszip");
let zip = new JSZip();
let photoZip = zip.folder(`${job.streetAddress}`);

useEffect(() => { 
     //// API call to load job info from dynamo db
  function loadJob() {
    return API.get("api name", "/tablename/tableinfo", {
  'queryStringParameters': {jobId: props.match.params.id}    
   }); 
  } 
   /// onload function to load job info and get a count of files
    async function onLoad() {   

      try {
        const job = await loadJob();
        setJob(job[0])

        const ImagesUploaded = await Storage.list(`${job[0].jobId}`);
        setImagesUploaded(ImagesUploaded);

        } catch (e) {
          alert(e);
      }

    }

    onLoad();
  }, [props.match.params.id,]);


  /// On download button click, loop through / download images using the key given from storage.list in onload function
  async function handleDownloadClick(event) {
         event.preventDefault();    
      const imagesAsArray = [...imagesUploaded];

    for (let i = 0; i < imagesAsArray.length; i++) {                                                                                          
      await DownloadFileFromS3(imagesAsArray[i]); 
        }
       /// waits for "await DownloadFileFromS3, then executes the save as which saves the zipped folder created in "DownloadFileFromS3"
        zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
             .then(function(content) {
        saveAs(content, `${job.streetAddress}`);
        });
   }


    /// download each file from s3 and put it in the zip folder
    async function DownloadFileFromS3(fileToDownload) {

        const result = await Storage.get(fileToDownload.key, {download: true})

        let mimeType = result.ContentType
        let fileName = fileToDownload.key
        let blob = new Blob([result.Body], {type: mimeType})

        photoZip.file(fileName[1], blob)

   }

 return(

      <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
      <IonButtons slot="start">
          <IonBackButton/>
      </IonButtons>
          <IonTitle>Download Images</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>  
      <IonContent className="ion-padding">   
      <IonButton onclick={handleDownloadClick}> download </IonButton>
      </IonContent>
      </IonPage>
    );


  }


export default withRouter(NewEditInfo);
```

Comment: The code you've shown seems to be running in the browser. Are you expecting the browser client to download the files from S3 directly and ZIP them locally within the browser? What is `Storage` that you are calling `get()` on? Would it make sense for your back-end to get these files from S3, compress in a ZIP file, and make that available to the web client?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is actually server-side process. Making a directory and put files together and then once you need to download it as the zip folder. It's better to look into AWS SDK. It has what you need.

Answer (score 4):

figured I would share my solution, as i've seen alot of questions about this, but not many helpful answers.

using JSZip: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

using saveAs from fileSaver.js: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

First: it loops through downloading each file individually from s3, creates a blob, and puts each blob/file into a "folder".

Second: after each file has been downloaded from s3, it will then use the saveAs method to download/save the zipped folder.

```
function NewEditInfo(props) {
const [job, setJob] = useState([]);
const [imagesUploaded, setImagesUploaded] = useState(null); 

//initialize jsZip
var JSZip = require("jszip");
let zip = new JSZip();
let photoZip = zip.folder(`${job.streetAddress}`);

useEffect(() => { 
     //// API call to load job info from dynamo db
  function loadJob() {
    return API.get("api name", "/tablename/tableinfo", {
  'queryStringParameters': {jobId: props.match.params.id}    
   }); 
  } 
   /// onload function to load job info and get a count of files
    async function onLoad() {   

      try {
        const job = await loadJob();
        setJob(job[0])

        const ImagesUploaded = await Storage.list(`${job[0].jobId}`);
        setImagesUploaded(ImagesUploaded);

        } catch (e) {
          alert(e);
      }

    }

    onLoad();
  }, [props.match.params.id,]);


  /// On download button click, loop through / download images using the key given from storage.list in onload function
  async function handleDownloadClick(event) {
         event.preventDefault();    
      const imagesAsArray = [...imagesUploaded];

    for (let i = 0; i < imagesAsArray.length; i++) {                                                                                          
      await DownloadFileFromS3(imagesAsArray[i]); 
        }
       /// waits for "await DownloadFileFromS3, then executes the save as which saves the zipped folder created in "DownloadFileFromS3"
        zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
             .then(function(content) {
        saveAs(content, `${job.streetAddress}`);
        });
   }


    /// download each file from s3 and put it in the zip folder
    async function DownloadFileFromS3(fileToDownload) {

        const result = await Storage.get(fileToDownload.key, {download: true})

        let mimeType = result.ContentType
        let fileName = fileToDownload.key
        let blob = new Blob([result.Body], {type: mimeType})

        photoZip.file(fileName[1], blob)

   }

 return(

      <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
      <IonButtons slot="start">
          <IonBackButton/>
      </IonButtons>
          <IonTitle>Download Images</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>  
      <IonContent className="ion-padding">   
      <IonButton onclick={handleDownloadClick}> download </IonButton>
      </IonContent>
      </IonPage>
    );


  }


export default withRouter(NewEditInfo);
```